# Can you include only certain forms during a compile

Tags: c#, .net, conditional-compilation

We are developing two versions of an application. Not in the sense of a lite vs standard version of the application, where one version will have limited functionality etc. We will actually be displaying different types of information in the application, depending on the version (that's the best way I can describe it without going into too many details).

To differentiate the two versions of the application we've considered using the conditional attribute and the #if directive (if there are any other options or better way than these two, I'm open for suggestions). After some research and debate, we've decided to go with the #if approach, since this will not include the unnecessary code during the compile process (whereas the conditional attribute will just remove the calls to the methods that do not meet the condition, but still include the methods... if I'm not mistaken). I realize the two are not mutually exclusive, so we could always mix and match if need be.

Anyway... What we're now wondering, is if there is a way to **only** include certain windows forms during a compile, based on which version of the application we are compiling. We have split out all of the logic, so the forms are really just forms, with very little code inside them (mostly just calls to form manager classes that handle all of the business logic). The form manager classes will contain some of the #if statements inside of them, so the code can be reused in both versions of the application, whenever possible (instead of making two classes and putting a conditional attribute on the classes... though maybe this is something we should consider).

Is anyone aware of a good way to do this?

TIA

UPDATE:

Just an FYI of what we actually decided to do. We put the different versions of the forms into separate namespaces and then only had to use an #if statement around the namespace using statement at the top of the class that manages all of the forms. Worked out pretty slick and was very litte work.

Comment: Why not simply putting the entire `Form` class inside a conditional if?

Comment: Would we have to do this for each of the partial class files (like the ones that are created by the designer with all the windows component code etc.)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do this with library projects.  I produce another project (.csproj), and then include into that project the existing sources.  In VS2008, right click on the new project, Click add Existing Item... and then *instead of clicking Add*, use the select arrow to select "Add as Link".

Rather than duplicating source modules, **Add as Link** will include a reference to the existing source, into the new project.  This way you can have N projects, each with a different combination of source modules.  I use this in concert with #if statements within the source of common modules to produce different versions of a library.

[Add Existing Item http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/th.eff09391e9.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/th.eff09391e9.png)
[full image](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?eff09391e9.png)

[Add as Link http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/th.f12b764887.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/th.f12b764887.png)
[full image](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?f12b764887.png)

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do this is using OO inheritance: put functionality that's common to both versions in a superclass, and then create separate subclasses which define the specializations of the superclass for each of your versions.

You can then build your superclass[es] as a shared library, and build each specialized subclass in separate assemblies (which reference the common shared library).

Doing this uses no conditional compilation nor conditional build options.

Comment: We may have to take this route... we didn't really realized we were going to have two versions of the application until we were well into the coding process. I was hoping there was an easier way, though this might not be tough since we've designed our logic in a modular way.

Comment: That works for everything but UI changes in the Visual Designer between the forms.

Answer (score 1):

The solution suggested by ChrisW is probably the correct way to do it. However, it may involve a lot of changes to your design, so here is another one : instead of having several configurations for the same project, create another project with the same sources. To do that, the easiest way is to create a copy of your .csproj file and include it in the solution